# when I use typescript compiler api, I found that interface ClassDeclaration contain optional property "name"

Tags: typescript, typescript-compiler-api

when I use typescript compiler api, I found that interface `ClassDeclaration` contain optional property `name`.
How can i get a `ClassDeclaration` Node without name?

I also found that interface `InterfaceDeclaration` contain a required property `name`.

Why it is different?

Answer (score 1):

A class declaration may not contain a name when exported as a default export.

```
export default class {
    method() {
    }
}
```

https://ts-ast-viewer.com/#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAE2AMwIYFcA28DGnUDOBcA3gFByVwC2wMAFhAgBQCUpFVAvmV0A

The same is not possible for an interface and it will raise a syntax error.

https://ts-ast-viewer.com/#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAE2AMwIYFcA28CWA7GYKNAY2DgG8AoAXyA

I'm not sure why they decided that, but not having to worry about the name not possibly being there does make things easier.